# I am training a model on GCP with "gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training" and it does not export a savedmodel.pb

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am using the code below to train a model on GCP locally. And it return an exported savedmodel.pb

```
%%bash
# Use Cloud Machine Learning Engine to train the model in local file system
gcloud ai-platform local train \
    --module-name=trainer.task \
    --package-path=${PWD}/${MODEL_NAME}/trainer \
    -- \
    --train_data_paths=${PWD}/HardResultsNoExtra55447_Cl5_25TrainSet.csv \
    --eval_data_paths=${PWD}/HardResultsNoExtra55447_Cl5_25EvalSet.csv  \
    --output_dir=${PWD}/${TRAINING_DIR}
```

But when I am running this code to train on GCP it does not return an export of the savemodel.pb

```
%%bash
OUTDIR=gs://${BUCKET}/${MODEL_NAME}/${TRAINING_DIR}
JOBNAME=${MODEL_NAME}_$(date -u +%y%m%d_%H%M%S)
echo $OUTDIR $REGION $JOBNAME
# Clear the Cloud Storage Bucket used for the training job
gsutil -m rm -rf $OUTDIR
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOBNAME \
   --region=$REGION \
   --module-name=trainer.task \
   --package-path=${PWD}/${MODEL_NAME}/trainer \
   --job-dir=$OUTDIR \
   --staging-bucket=gs://$BUCKET \
   --scale-tier=BASIC \
   --runtime-version 2.2 \
   --python-version 3.7 \
   -- \
   --train_data_paths="gs://${BUCKET}/${MODEL_NAME}/HardResultsNoExtra55447_Cl5_25TrainSet.csv" \
   --eval_data_paths="gs://${BUCKET}/${MODEL_NAME}/HardResultsNoExtra55447_Cl5_25EvalSet.csv"  \
   --output_dir=$OUTDIR \
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup



REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'tensorflow==2.2.0',
    'future==0.18.2',
]

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='AI Platform | Training | Base'
)
```

task.py

```
import argparse
import json
import os




from . import model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # Input Arguments
    parser.add_argument(
        '--train_data_paths',
        help = 'GCS or local path to training data',
        required = True
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--train_batch_size',
        help = 'Batch size for training steps',
        type = int,
        default = 512
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--train_steps',
        help = 'Steps to run the training job for',
        type = int
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--eval_steps',
        help = 'Number of steps to run evalution for at each checkpoint',
        default = 10,
        type = int
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--eval_data_paths',
        help = 'GCS or local path to evaluation data',
        required = True
    )
    # Training arguments
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output_dir',
        help = 'GCS location to write checkpoints and export models',
        required = True
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--job-dir',
        help = 'this model ignores this field, but it is required by gcloud',
        default = 'junk'
    )

    # Eval arguments
    parser.add_argument(
        '--eval_delay_secs',
        help = 'How long to wait before running first evaluation',
        default = 10,
        type = int
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--throttle_secs',
        help = 'Seconds between evaluations',
        default = 300,
        type = int
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    arguments = args.__dict__

    # Unused args provided by service
    arguments.pop('job_dir', None)
    arguments.pop('job-dir', None)

    # output_dir = arguments['output_dir']
    # Append trial_id to path if we are doing hptuning
    # This code can be removed if you are not using hyperparameter tuning
    # output_dir = os.path.join(
    #     output_dir,
    #     json.loads(
    #         os.environ.get('TF_CONFIG', '{}')
    #     ).get('task', {}).get('trail', '')
    # )

    # Run the training job
    model.train_and_evaluate(arguments)
```

model.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import shutil

tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.INFO)

# List the CSV columns
CSV_COLUMNS = 'X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,X10,X'.split(',')

#Choose which column is your label
LABEL_COLUMN = 'X'

# Set the default values for each CSV column in case there is a missing value
DEFAULTS = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]]


# Create an input function reading a file using the Dataset API
# Then provide the results to the Estimator APItensorboard --logdir=./27-TensorFlow_Desgo4_2016-2019_Data_NoExtra_CL5-25COUNTS/Trained_models/_trained
def read_dataset(filename, mode, batch_size = 44200):
  def _input_fn():
    def decode_csv(value_column):
      columns = tf.compat.v1.decode_csv(value_column, record_defaults=DEFAULTS)
      features = dict(zip(CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
      label = features.pop(LABEL_COLUMN)
      return features, label
    
    # Create list of files that match pattern
    file_list = tf.compat.v1.gfile.Glob(filename)

    # Create dataset from file list
    dataset = (tf.compat.v1.data.TextLineDataset(file_list)  # Read text file
                 .map(decode_csv))  # Transform each elem by applying decode_csv fn
      
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        num_epochs = None # indefinitely
        #dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10*batch_size)
    else:
        num_epochs = 1 # end-of-input after this
 
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs).batch(batch_size)
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
  return _input_fn

# Define your feature columns
INPUT_COLUMNS = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X1'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X2'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X3'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X4'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X5'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X6'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X7'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X8'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X9'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X10')
]

# Create a function that will augment your feature set
def add_more_features(feats):
    # Nothing to add (yet!)
    return feats

feature_cols = add_more_features(INPUT_COLUMNS)

# Create your serving input function so that your trained model will be able to serve predictions
def serving_input_fn():
    feature_placeholders = {
        column.name: tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None]) for column in INPUT_COLUMNS
    }

    features = feature_placeholders
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, feature_placeholders)

# Create an estimator that we are going to train and evaluate

def train_and_evaluate(args):
  tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriterCache.clear()  
  estimator = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesRegressor(
                       model_dir = args['output_dir'],
                       feature_columns = feature_cols,
                       n_trees=500,
                       max_depth=6,
                       learning_rate=0.1,
                       l1_regularization=0.0,
                       l2_regularization=0.0,
                       n_batches_per_layer=1)
  train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
                       input_fn = read_dataset(args['train_data_paths'],
                       mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN),
                       max_steps = args['train_steps'])
  exporter = tf.estimator.LatestExporter('exporter', serving_input_fn, exports_to_keep=1)
  eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
        input_fn = read_dataset(args['eval_data_paths'],
                       mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL),
        steps = None,
        start_delay_secs = 60, # start evaluating after N seconds
        throttle_secs = args['throttle_secs'],  # evaluate every N seconds
        exporters = exporter)
  tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

If there is anymore information that one would need please let me know. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try a local training with a GCS bucket and not a local path? Did you wait the end of the training to check your bucket? Do you see some file or directory in your bucket? event if it's not a model.pb?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Did you try a local training with a GCS bucket and not a local path? no

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Did you wait the end of the training to check your bucket? yes

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Do you see some file or directory in your bucket? All my check points are there and a graph.pbtxt.

Comment: In my case, I have the `graph.pbtxt` file here: `gs://..../dnn/` and the `saved_model.pb` in the export/exporter directory, like this`gs://..../dnn/export/exporter/1545427740`. Does it the same for you?

Comment: No I don't. There's no export/exporter folder.

Comment: Not having the export folder is the only difference when I train local vs submitting a job.

Comment: How long take your training? Did you try to reduce the start_delay_secs and the throttle_secs values (I have mines to 10). And I don't have the exports_to_keep param. I don't know if that can be the source of the problem!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere. For stater Thank you very much for your time, it is appreciated a lot. Now, the training takes around 3 hours + . I have notice that, when I start the training locally (gcloud ai-platform local train) , the export folder appears a soon as the check points get recorded. That does not happen when training on GCP (gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training). Note that I use LatestExporter as exporter.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Would be great to fix it